# When no network - save data to sqlite and send to server once network regained

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

This is Ionic 2+ - I retrieve an array of objects upon load. When the network is present and the user performs an action, that object itemID is then sent that API endpoint. When there isn't any network, the itemID should be saved to the SQLite DB, then pushed to the API endpoint once the network is restored.

Component

Saving array of initial objects to save to db.

```
private createDB(): void{  
      this.sqlite.create({
        name: 'DATABASE_FILE_NAME',
        location: 'default'
      }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
          this.db = db;
          this.createTables();
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
      }

      private createTables(): void{
        this.db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "ITEMS" ( `rowid` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `something` BOOL, `something` BOOL, `itemID` INT )', {}).then((res) => { console.log(res, 'Executed SQL')
          }).catch(e => console.log(e));

      }
```

Array I'm retrieving

```
[
    {itemID: 10, something: "blue", something: "1"}
    {itemID: 11, something: "red", something: "2"}
    {itemID: 12, something: "green", something: "2"}
    {itemID: 13, something: "yellow", something: "1"}
]
```

Send action function to server

```
 this.service.sendAction(itemID).subscribe(result => {})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save data to **SQLite** even if there is a network connection and then send it to API. In that case you can use only statemen in `else` from first step.

Below is the scenario you are looking for.

1.) Save data to SQLite (**page.ts**)

```
callApi(){
  if(this._connectivityService.isOnline()){
  this.service.sendAction(itemID).subscribe(result => {})
  } else {
  this._databaseService.sendAction(itemID).then(result => {})
  }
}
```

2.) Next step can be on Dashboard or Homepage where you will check network connectivity and send data from SQLite to API once when network is there. (**dashboard.ts**)

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
     this.sendData();
 }
```

Function that sends data from SQLite to API.

```
sendData(){
    this.count = 0;
    this._database.getLocalData().then((result) => {
        this.DataList = <Array<Object>> result;
        if(this.DataList.length !== 0){
          this.DataList.forEach(function(item) {
            this.service.sendAction(item).subscribe(result => {
            if(res.status == "ok" && this.count == this.DataList.length-1){ 
               //empty SQLite local table if success
                this._database.deleteLocalData();
             }
            })
           }
        } else {
          //       
        } 
    }, (error) => {
            console.log("Offline data not sent!", 
      error);
    });
  }
```

Below is the example of SQLite table for stored data. (**database-service.ts**)

```
public getLocalData() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.sqlite.create({
        name: 'dbName.db',
        location: 'default'
        })
        .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
            db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM tableName", []).then((data) => {
                let DataList = [];
                if(data.rows.length > 0) {
                    for(let i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
                       DataList.push({
                            itemID: data.rows.item(i).itemID,
                            something: data.rows.item(i).something
                        });
                    }
                }
                resolve(DataList);
            }, (error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
            })
         .catch(e => console.log(e));
        });
    }
```

Comment: How would I get the table tableName if it's not created? I should have asked that earlier. Or would I create the table initially from my question and use that example you have provided on top of that?

Comment: @userlkjsflkdsvm You should create table initially. I usually use separate service/provider for all tables. See example  http://www.tomislavstankovic.com/blog/ionic-2-3-sqlite-servis/

Comment: The issue I'm having is, I just want to save an object and not an array. Just like in my example I'm only sending an object to that api and not an array of objects.

Comment: In example above you are saving object "*this._databaseService.sendAction(object).then(result => {})*", but as far as sending data from SQLite to API "*sendData()*" if you do not want array just remove "*DataList*". In that case, if there is no network connection longer time you can't save more than one object to SQLite database.

Comment: That's the issue I guess, using your example it's wanting me to send an array and not an object. I agree with you, I do want to save an array, so I can store more objects.

Comment: Nevermind I think I got it working, thanks! I'll follow up

Comment: One thing is I'm getting the same datalist.length value every time I go through the loop - this.DataList.length-1

Comment: But I figured it out. Thanks for the help!!